# Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey userscript on all upon tabs?

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I've made a context menu to execute a function in GM/TM.  Is it possible to execute a function in all open tabs?

If I were to create a userscript with a single command like:

```
location.reload();
```

Is it possible to reload all open tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of, but also not really.

You can use `GM_setValue('X', 'Y');` to store a value. You could try and find a way to create a communication protocol that allows you to signal tabs to reload. But I suspect this function is not atomic and it would be rather difficult for you to ensure tabs don't reload twice, or know that they have all reloaded (or performed whatever action you needed).

Second problem is that browsers suspend tabs, either completely or by significantly slowing down their event loop, so it might take a while for the message to be noted.

If you just want an action to happen once and do not need any feedback, you can try this pseudocode:

```
function triggerAction(actionName) {
    GM_setValue("newAction", {token:randomNumber(), action:actionName});
}

// main loop, this should be an async function
async main() {
    while(true) {
        await someDelayFunction(500 ms);
        // check action
        currentAction = GM_getValue("newAction");
        // session storage is a per-tab permanent memory
        if(sessionStorage.SCRIPT_lastActionToken != currentAction.token) {
            sessionStorage.SCRIPT_lastActionToken = currentAction.token;
            performAction(currentAction.action);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: ** this is just pseudocode to illustrate the idea.

Comment: `GM_setValue` (in contrast with `localStorage`) accepts an object as a second parameter, so there is no need to use `JSON.parse`/`JSON.stringify`.